# How can I know when the line number has changed?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, c-strings

I know that I can store words (as strings) in char arrays that have enough space.

In the particular example I have an array of 3 strings that are 5 bytes each.
This is the way I take the words from a line:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char **array;
    array = (char **)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *)); // allocation

    for( i = 0; i <= 2; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char)); // allocation
    }

    /* now I store the words */
    i = 0;
    while(i <= 2)
    {
        scanf("%s", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

How can I know when the line number has changed?

Comment: Aside: Use `scanf("%s", array[i]);` --> `scanf("%4s", array[i]);` to prevent buffer overruns.

Comment: "to know when the line has changed' `scanf("%s", array[i]);` does not keep track of lines as `'\n'` are consume first and not tallied.  Use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of user input.  Code needs a new approach.

Comment: why do you use `malloc()` for such a small array when its dimensions are known at compiletime?

Comment: OT: By convention this `i<=2` typically is coded as `i<3`.

Comment: i know but i prefer i<=2

Answer (score -1):

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZEOF_ARRAY(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((*x)))

int peek(FILE *stream)
{
    return ungetc(fgetc(stream), stream);
}

int main()
{
    char words[3][5] = { 0 };
    size_t words_read = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZEOF_ARRAY(words); ++words_read, ++i) {
        if (scanf("%4s", words[i]) != 1)
            break;

        int ch;  // discard non-whitespace characters that exceeded available storage:
        while ((ch = peek(stdin)) != EOF && !isspace(ch))
            fgetc(stdin);

        // discard whitespace until a newline is encountered:
        while ((ch = peek(stdin)) != EOF && isspace(ch) && ch != '\n')
            fgetc(stdin);

        if (ch == '\n') {
            puts("NEWLINE!");
            fgetc(stdin);  // remove the newline from the stream
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < words_read; ++i)
        printf("%2zu: \"%s\"\n", i, words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello guys i found a solution.Just After i get a string i will getchar() to see if it is '\n.btw thnx